# Pyramid: View defined in a separate file not being associated with a route

Tags: python, pyramid

I have the following in my `__init__.py` file.

```
config = Configurator(settings=settings)

config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
config.include('pathshala.routes.all_routes')

config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

config.scan()
```

I have defined all routes in `routes.py` which has:

```
def all_routes(config):
    config.add_route('sis_add_student', '/sis/add')
```

All views are defined in the `views.py` file (in the same package) which has:

```
@view_config(route_name='sis_add_student')
def add_student_view(request):
    return Response("Hey there!")
```

However, when I try opening the path `/sis/add`, I get a 404 error. The Debug Toolbar suggests that the correct route has been identified but no view has been associated with that route.

Interestingly, if I move the view declaration to `__init__.py`, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like my `config.scan()` is to blame because it fails to associate a view only when the declaration is in another file but I'm not sure about that and don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot have a package named `views` in your project. I had declared `views` as a package. Removing that by deleting the `__init__.py` from the views directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on doing it the fancy way, you can do something like

```
from .routes import add_routes

config = Configurator(settings=settings)    
config.include('pyramid_jinja2')

add_routes(config)

config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

config.scan()
```

in my app I did it this way because I wasn't aware of `config.include()`, and it does work :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

What is .routes and add_routes? Is it part of the Pyramid library itself or is it the file where you've defined your routes? I'm asking because I'm getting an import error.

Comment: Never mind! I assume .routes refers to the routes.py file and add_routes is the method which defines the routes. 

Using that, just like before, the routes are matched correctly but no view is associated to that route. I assumed I could do something like `from .views import *' but adding that didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm, ok, so the routes are registered correctly, but the scan phase does not seem to work? Do you have some unusual circular imports - like, `import views` in `__init__py` and `import pathshala.blah` in `views.py` - possibly via some intermediate files? Do you have `if __name__ == '__main__':` thingie in your `__init__.py`? Also I would try specifying the `package` parameter of the `scan()` method

Comment: No I'm not importing anything other than `Response` and `view_config` in my view declaration. Also, do I really need the `__name__ == '__main__':` thing? Isn't that just for when I'm creating a project without using any scaffold? The Wiki tutorial at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/definingviews.html doesn't contain that. How should I put that?

Also, I added the package name in the `scan()` method but that didn't help.

Comment: If your code looks like that in the tutorial (configurator is created inside the `main()` function) then it should be ok. I was excluding the possibility of the configurator being created in the module scope, which would make the code to run at import time...

Comment: Turns out I had a `views` directory declared as a package. Removing the `__init__.py` file from the views directory solved the problem.

Thanks a lot! :)